# Get the count of statuses by date but only count continuous rows

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2016, continuous

I have this data:

```
ID  Name        Status  Date
1   Machine1    Active  2018-01-01
2   Machine2    Fault   2018-01-01
3   Machine3    Active  2018-01-01
4   Machine1    Fault   2018-01-02
5   Machine2    Active  2018-01-02
6   Machine3    Active  2018-01-02
7   Machine2    Active  2018-01-03
8   Machine1    Fault   2018-01-03
9   Machine2    Active  2018-01-04
10  Machine1    Fault   2018-01-04
11  Machine3    Active  2018-01-06
```

**INPUT**

and i want these data in output

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
Name           Last Status  Count
Machine1         Fault       3  
Machine2         Active      3  
Machine3         Active      1       Because Date is not Continuous
```

*Count : Last number of status in continuous history

Comment: What is your code and what error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If I understood your proeblem correctly, please improve/clarify your question by adding this wording: 
"Last Status" is the most recently given status of a particular machine
"Count" is the number of distinct consecutive days this status has been reported up to the most recent date. If there is a gap in the dates (no record for a particular date/machine/status), the counter is reset

Comment: You're sample data doesn't match the expected output: 
`Machine2 is Active for 3 days from 2 Jan to 4 Jan`
`Machine3 is Active for 2 days from 1 Jan to 2 Jan`

Comment: @Mazhar I agree with the error in machine 2, it has been active for the last 3 days, but Machine 3 has been most recently active, and this active is 1 day long report only, so that is correct.

Comment: [I wrote a query](http://rextester.com/SHF56182) which I thought would solve the problem, then saw your requirement about continuous history.  If a date is missing, why wouldn't the space between non continuous dates _not_ have the same status?  I think it would be OK to assume this.

Comment: @CaiusJard Machine 3 was active on the 1 Jan and then again on the 2 Jan, this is two days.

Comment: @Mazhar, most recently on the 6th of jan the machine was active, there is no record for 5th of jan, the longest run of consecutive reports, heading back into the past from the most recent day(6th jan) is 1 day (the 6th of jan). Said another way.. "every time there is a break in the date numbering for a partiocular machine, all the reports before the break are discarded"

Comment: Ah, take into account the most recent only discard the rest. Get ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is as simple as this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        Name,
        Status,
        DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Status ORDER BY Date DESC) - 1, Date) AS GroupingDate
    FROM testdata
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        Name,
        Status,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY GroupingDate DESC) AS GroupingNumber
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT Name, Status AS LastStatus, COUNT(*) AS LastStatusCount
FROM cte2
WHERE GroupingNumber = 1
GROUP BY Name, Status
ORDER BY Name
```

[Result and DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1c12e0a69de16bcb5cb6d9fccf0d4aee):

```
| Name     | LastStatus | LastStatusCount |
|----------|------------|-----------------|
| Machine1 | Fault      | 3               |
| Machine2 | Active     | 3               |
| Machine3 | Active     | 1               |
```

In order to understand how this works, look at the intermediate values generated by CTE:

```
| Name     | Status | Date                | RowNumber | GroupingDate        | GroupingNumber |
|----------|--------|---------------------|-----------|---------------------|----------------|
| Machine1 | Fault  | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1         | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1              |
| Machine1 | Fault  | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 | 2         | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1              |
| Machine1 | Fault  | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 | 3         | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1              |
| Machine1 | Active | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1         | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 | 4              |
| Machine2 | Active | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1         | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1              |
| Machine2 | Active | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 | 2         | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1              |
| Machine2 | Active | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 | 3         | 04/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1              |
| Machine2 | Fault  | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1         | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 | 4              |
| Machine3 | Active | 06/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1         | 06/01/2018 00:00:00 | 1              |
| Machine3 | Active | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 | 2         | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 | 2              |
| Machine3 | Active | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 | 3         | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 | 2              |
```

The trick here is that if two numbers are contiguous then subtracting contiguous numbers from them will result in same value. E.g. if we have `5, 6, 8, 9` then subtracting `1, 2, 3, 4` in that order will produce `4, 4, 5, 5`.

Comment: Neat trick; here Salman establishes an incrementing counter that is added to a decrementing date. For consecutive dates, this naturally produces a fixed output date (3rd jan + 0 = 3rd jan, 2nd jan + 1 = 3rd jan, 1st jan + 2 = 3rd jan), then the data is ranked by this. Rank produces the same "winning position" for equal values so all of the consecutive dates that became the same output date are all ranked first. These are then grouped and counted

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, though SQLFiddle is having a fit at the moment, so I can't test:

```
SELECT [Name], [Status], ct as [Count]
FROM (
 SELECT 
  [name], 
  [status], 
  [date],
  1 + (SUM( grp ) OVER (PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING ) * grp) ct,
  row_number() over(partition by [name] order by [date] desc) rn
 FROM
 (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY [date] ) = DATEADD(day, -1, [date]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END grp
  FROM t
 ) x
) y
WHERE
  rn = 1
```

It first off uses LAG to look at the current row and the previous row (grouping the data into machine name and status, ordering the data by date) and if the current date is 1 day different to the previous date it records a 1 else a 0

These 1s and zeroes are summed in a running total fashion, resetting when the machine name or status changes (the partition of the sum() over() )

Also we want to consider the data just in terms of the machine name, and we only want the latest record from each machine, so we partition by the machine name, and count in order of date descending, then just pick (with the where clause) the rows that are numbered 1 for each machine

*It actually makes a lot more sense if you run the queries separately, like this*

Calculate the "is the current report consecutive with the previous report, for the given status and machine" 1 = yes, 0 = no:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY [date] ) = DATEADD(day, -1, [date]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END grp
  FROM t
```

Calculate the "what is the running total of the current block of consecutive reports":

```
SELECT 
  [name], 
  [status], 
  [date],
  1 + (SUM( grp ) OVER (PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING ) * grp) ct,
  row_number() over(partition by [name] order by [date] desc) rn
 FROM
 (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY [date] ) = DATEADD(day, -1, [date]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END grp
  FROM t
 ) x
```

Then of course, the whole thing but without the where clause, so you can see the data we're discarding:

```
SELECT [Name], [Status], ct as [Count]
FROM (
 SELECT 
  [name], 
  [status], 
  [date],
  1 + (SUM( grp ) OVER (PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING ) * grp) ct,
  row_number() over(partition by [name] order by [date] desc) rn
 FROM
 (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY [name], [status] ORDER BY [date] ) = DATEADD(day, -1, [date]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END grp
  FROM t
 ) x
) y
```

Fiddle finally woke up:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77dae/2